# If for any element's neighbors' average equals to element in sequence, it is an arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I need to prove that if a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is such that
$$
a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}{2} \quad\forall n\in\Bbb N
$$
then the sequence is arithmetic progression.

I transformed that formula to the following one:
$${a_n-a_{n-1}}=a_{n+1}-a_n$$
And at this point it's pretty obvious that we could say the diffrence between the element and his neighbors is the same, so it is an arithmetic progression.

But I think for a strong proof I need to use induction, but i don't really understand, how could I solve it with induction. I know how to used, but how to apply it here?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need induction.

Comment: Oh, thanks! How should i proof it then?

Comment: Your formula ${a_n-a_{n-1}}=a_{n+1}-a_n$ holds for all $n\ge 2$ and that is a proof.

Comment: Depending on the definition of an arithmetic progression (eg $a_i - a_{i-1} = a_j - a_{j-1}$ for any $i, j \ge 1$), this could be an elementary exercise in induction on $|j - i|$.